# Enabling Virtualization in a dual boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, grub

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8 installed and a grub loader appears at startup for OS selection. I have installed vmware in my Windows partition, and it requires Intel Virtualization to be enabled before installing the OS in virtual machine. Settings for VT-x enable/disable usually appear in BIOS loader for Windows but since I have grub installed, I can't figure out how to enable virtualization there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your Specs.

Comment: BIOS doesn't relate anything to grub or the Windows bootloader because it starts up even sooner than the bootloaders to load the bootloader and it's the first program to start in computers. Press some key (normally del/F1/F2/F9/F10/F11/F12 depending on computers) right after pressing power key to enter it

Answer (score 0):

*snip*

> it requires Intel Virtualization to be enabled

OK, this is our goal. Enable VT-x.

> Settings for VT-x enable/disable usually appear in BIOS loader for Windows

The is no BIOS loader for windows.

A simplified start process works as follows:
1) Power gets turned on
2) Motherboard starts executing its firmware (e.g. the BIOS or EFI).
3) The firmware reads some saved settings (e.g. enable or disable ports is stored here. Boot from which device. Enable or disable VT-x, shopw full screen logo or useful text, ...)
4) Firmware tries to load the next step from disk (e.g. bootcode from an MBR).
5) That loaded program takes over. And loads a larger chunk from disk. This larger chunk can be grub, or the windowsbootloader.

Checking if the firmware wants to disable VT-x happens way before you get to grub.

What you want to do is:
a) Go to the BIOS and check if it has a VT-X disable.
b) if not found then check if your CPU supports it.
c) if is still not works check if your motherboard supports it. (Some disable it without option to enable it. So this is a (a) with no option to turn it on.
d) Only after that you should check for software which disables it after it was on during boot.